# Entity Framework Core Design into SharedLibrary into Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, entity-framework-core

I'm currently trying to Import my MariaDB local DataBase into my .NET Core Web Server using the Entity Framework Core Design scaffold feature, them exporting my Dll into Unity.

My shared library project has .NET 6.0 as target framework
NuGet packages:

1. Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.NewtonsoftJson - Version 6.0.20

My Server project has .NET 6.0 as target framework
NuGet packages:

1. Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer - Version 6.0.20
2. Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore - Version 6.0.20
3. Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design - Version 6.0.20
4. Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens - Version 6.32.0
5. Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql - Version 6.0.2
6. runtime.native.System.Security.Cryptography - Version 4.3.4
7. System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt - Version 6.32.0
8. System.Security.Claims - Version 4.3.0

Unity Version 2022.3.5f1

.NET SDK Versions : 7.0.101 & 6.0.412 -- I've made sure that I'm using 6.0.412 while compiling

### Ask for more version related things if needed.

I'm hosting my DB with Xampp and I can make connection to the database using posts - I can create new rows using endpoints.

I start by using the following command in CMD in order to import the DB structure into my .NET server files:

```
dotnet ef dbcontext scaffold `
>> "server=********;port=********;user=********;password=********;database=********;" `
>> Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql `
>> --output-dir Models `
>> --context DbContext `
```

After a successful import, with all my files in the project, I move the Database table classes into my SharedLibrary and DbContext into the server project root folder. Rename the namespaces accordingly.

Build both the Server and Library without any errors.

the Dll is automatically moved into the Unity folder by using a post build event.

copy SharedLibrary.dll

```
$(OutPut)..\..\..\..\..\USP\Assets\DLLs\SharedLibrary.dll</PostBuildEvent>
```

When Unity reloads the scripts it return 2 errors:

```
Unable to load attribute info on field SharedLibrary.Ability::<Id>k__BackingField. Are you missing a reference?
```

```
Unloading broken assembly Assets/DLLs/SharedLibrary.dll, this assembly can cause crashes in the runtime
```

What am I doing wrong here?

I've tried:
Changing framework versions
Updating Unity version
Checking DB fk's both at phpmyadmin and MySQL Workbench
Partially rebuilt the DB structure with MySQL Workbench to make sure fk's were correct

I'm expecting to figure out what is happening and finally be able to import my Dll into unity.

Edit: Sample of table Unity is complaining about:

```
namespace SharedLibrary
{
    public partial class Ability
    {
        public Ability()
        {
            Abilityaoeinfos = new HashSet<Abilityaoeinfo>();
            Abilityaurainfos = new HashSet<Abilityaurainfo>();
            Abilitydamageinfos = new HashSet<Abilitydamageinfo>();
            Abilityinfos = new HashSet<Abilityinfo>();
            Userabilitystats = new HashSet<Userabilitystat>();
            Items = new HashSet<Item>();
        }

        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string AbilityType { get; set; } = null!;
        public sbyte IsMonsterOnly { get; set; }
        public int? IsCodeTag { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<Abilityaoeinfo> Abilityaoeinfos { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<Abilityaurainfo> Abilityaurainfos { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<Abilitydamageinfo> Abilitydamageinfos { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<Abilityinfo> Abilityinfos { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<Userabilitystat> Userabilitystats { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<Item> Items { get; set; }
    }
}
```

One of the table that have reference to Item:

```
namespace SharedLibrary
{
    public partial class Abilityaoeinfo
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public float? Radius { get; set; }
        public float? Duration { get; set; }
        public string? Abilityaoeinfocol { get; set; }
        public int AbilityId { get; set; }

        public virtual Ability Ability { get; set; } = null!;
    }
}
```

edit 3: I've tried removing the table that unity was complaining from the Library and Unity simply started complaining about the next one (ordered alphabetically)
It might be indeed something to do with Unity only being .NET 4.7 compatible. Am I using features that .NET 6.0 has but .NET 4.7 hasn't?

edit 4: I think I've done it, My library was auto generating global using's, I removed that in the Library proj file :
enable.

I'm unsure if I'll encounter more problems related to this but I'll keep you updated if I do

Comment: What makes you think unity uses .net 6?

Comment: Nothing does, but I've also tried before with 3 tables still targeting .NET 6.0 and it worked. but anyways I tried 5.0 with the appropriate package versions and it returned the same errors.

edit1 :But anyway, if that's what's happening which version should I target? Could I still use the scaffold feature to import the classes into unity?

edit2: I just rechecked, the guide I was checking did in fact use .NET 6.0 for the library and it worked

Comment: ive only seen success with 4.7 which is why i ask

Comment: I've seen that while trying to fix my error but then must be another way to do this, other than building all classes and DbContext by hand... Am I missing something?

Comment: why use a DLL though? We also had a similar setup, an Asp.NET backend server - Unity frontend application - and a shared library containing all types between those. But there is no need to go through a DLL at all - simply make your shared library fulfill the requirements to be installed as a [package](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/CustomPackages.html) (have a `package.json` + assembly definitions) + keep the `csproj` in order to reference it in you backend project. We hosted both backend and frontend in the same repository without any issue ;)